# Is property key answers[value] being returned as a global variable?

Tags: javascript, memoization

The function isPrime has a property called answers and a property key called value. If isPrime.answers[value] returns [value] at the end of the function, is [value] now a variable outside of its defined function and simultaneously a property key of the answers object?

```
function isPrime(value) {
  if (!isPrime.answers) {
    isPrime.answers = {};
  }

  if (isPrime.answers[value] !== undefined) {
    return isPrime.answers[value];
  }

  var prime = value !== 1; // 1 is not a prime

  for (var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
    if (value % i === 0) {
      prime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
}
```

Comment: The only global in this example is the `isPrime` function object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is [value] a property key of the answers object?

Yes it is. The value of that key-value pair is `prime`.

> is [value] now a variable outside of its defined function?

No. The last line

```
 return isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
```

is equivalent to:

```
 isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
 return prime;
```

so it stores `prime` (a boolean) inside the object (under the key that `value` contains), and returns it. Returning a variable from a function does not change the variable itself in any way, it doesn't become a global, just it's value (the boolean) gets returned.

Both `value` and `prime` are local variables of `isPrime`.